# Throw away all text after a blank line in bash

Tags: bash

Using bash, I want to throw away all of the text in a file *after* the first blank line.  The blank line is used as a delimiter between records, and I only want the first record in the file.  Unfortunately, the number of lines per record can change depending on what the record refers to exactly, so I can't just keep the first *n* lines as a global solution.

[EDIT] Here is a solution that works:

```
qstat -f > out.tmp
grep -A90 -B0 $1 out.tmp > out2.txt
awk '/^$/{exit}{print}' out2.txt
rm out.tmp out2.txt
```

where $1 points to the name of the text file to be analyzed (passed as an argument to the script that I'm writing).  Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code that we can comment on? What have you tried, where is the problem?

Comment: There wasn't really a 'problem', I just wasn't sure how to do something.  I'll remember to include what code I have on my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with pretty much any generic text processing tool, e.g.:

```
awk '$0==""{exit}{print}'
awk '/^$/{exit}{print}'
sed '/^$/q'
```